# how to have a blast xml file in a readable and understandable way

Tags: blast

I got a blast xml file after a DNA sequence search. The XML file is not very readable. What is the way to make it more understandable? This blast contains about twenty matches. [Here is the xml file](https://www.grosfichiers.com/Hm7h8kqcjW5)

Comment: You can do this using the Bio Entrez parser in Biopython. Its quite easy to use, but its not clear whether your happy using Python.

Answer (score 2):

The most human-readable blast output formats are 0-4, e.g. `-outfmt 0` - which if I am not mistaken is the format used by web blast. However, these formats are a pain to automatically parse.

As [Cowboy_Patrick](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/13732/1642) pointed out, XML is more of a machine-readable format. The tabular output format ( `-outfmt 6`) is very commonly used, because it is easily parsed by unix command-line tools, and its structure also allows a somewhat easy human reading and understanding.

Comment: Many thanks, how to set the output format as -outfmt 6 in a line of python code as
 result = NCBIWWW.qblast('blastn','nt',ADN.format('fasta') ) ?

Comment: @serpipanton I am unfamiliar with BioPython, but a cursory look at the documentation suggests -outfmt 6 is unavailable for NCBIWWW.qblast. However, there is a module NCBIXML, which will allow you to easily parse the xml output.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for: https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer ? XML is a format designed to be readable firstly by machines, not humans.

With xslt you can convert XML to various more readable formats see this blog for something that fits your XML: http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2008/05/ncbi-blast-xslt-xhtml-svg.html?m=1